# Blank info going into database

Tags: php

Here's the code. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. The form is submitting in the database but it's blank.

```
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if(!$link){
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link); 

if(!$db_selected){
die('can not use' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}
$value = $_POST['hit'];
$value = $_POST['amount'];
$value = $_POST['category'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO hit (hit) VALUES ('$value')";

if(!mysql_query($sql)){
die('Error: ' . mysql_Error());
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

and here's the form

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Post Hits</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table tr > td { text-align: right; }
        table tr > td + td { text-align: left; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="he.php" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Hit:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea name="hit" rows="3"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    amount:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id = "amount" name="amount" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    category:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="category" id="category">
                        <option value="">- Choose -</option>
                        <option value="Blue">survey</option>
                        <option value="Green">batch</option>
                        <option value="Orange">misc</option>
                        <option value="Red">masters</option>
                        <option value="Yellow">qual</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit!" />

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am still very new with all of this so whatever mistake i am doing, it isnt obvious to me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many problems and error in your code. At first stage you are using the same variable for all the value you want to get from your `POST` data

```
$value = $_POST['hit'];
$value = $_POST['amount'];
$value = $_POST['category'];
```

Should be

```
$hit = $_POST['hit'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
```

So your query will look like

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO hit (hit) VALUES ('$hit')";
```

Or if you want all data to be inserted you should do

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO hit (hit, amount, category) VALUES ('$hit', '$amount', '$category')";
```

Then I  would like to remember you that `mysql_` functions are deprecated so i would advise you to switch to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and indeed you are at risk of `sql injection`, have a look here [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). You should use prepared statment to avoid any risk

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the value of `$value` at each stage here:

```
$value = $_POST['hit'];
$value = $_POST['amount'];
$value = $_POST['category'];
```

Which would make `$value` only equal to the last time you assigned it a value, in this case it would only be equal to `$_POST["category"]`.
You should store each of your `$_POST` data in a separate variable like this :

```
$hit = $_POST['hit'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
```

Then insert it into your query like this `$sql = "INSERT INTO hit (hit,amount,category) VALUES ('$hit','$amount','$category')";`

Also you should look into securing your data from SQL Injection, by using `PDO` or `mysqli` to do your database transactions.